# How to make an NSControl (e.g., NSTokenField) ignore mouse events

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstokenfield, nsresponder

Specifically, I'd like to make an `NSTokenField` ignore mouse events because I'm using it in a `NSTableCellView` just to display data in a tokenized way without allowing any editing.

Setting the token field's `enabled = NO` works, except that it greys out the tokens and makes it hard to read the text.

Setting the token field's `editable = NO` is pretty close to what I want—it prevents editing while preserving the token field's look—except that when I mouse over the tokens, they light up. If I could just prevent that, I'd be in business.

I suspect I need to subclass something and override some `NSResponder` methods, but not quite sure what to do. I tried subclassing `NSTokenField` and overriding `mouseEntered:` and `mouseMoved:` to do nothing, but that didn't work either.

Comment: The field is probably using a [tracking area](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/Reference/Reference.html) to get those mouse entry/exit events. Not sure exactly why overriding `mouseEntered:` screwed up drawing, but you could try `[field setTrackingArea:nil]` on a non-subclassed field and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out—turned out that when I created the class, `drawRect:` was being overridden so that it did nothing. I tried `for (NSTrackingArea *trackingArea in [tokenField trackingAreas]) {
        [tokenField removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    }`, but no dice. Also, I tried overriding `mouseMoved:` in addition to `mouseEntered:`, but that didn't work either…

Comment: @yuji: I don't have my machine with me at the moment to test, so I'm out of ideas.  You might want to just write your own replacement for this class.  Look at `BWToolkit` for an example.

Comment: Did you try setSelectable:NO ?

Comment: @rdelmar `setSelectable:NO` doesn't hurt, but doesn't do anything beyond what `setEditable:NO` does.

Comment: @IuliusCæsar turns out you had the right idea—wrote up an answer based on it. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a lot of stuff, I finally got this to work based on Iulius Cæsar's suggestion.

The trick was to subclass `NSTextField` and override `trackingAreas`:

```
- (NSArray *)trackingAreas
{
    return [NSArray array];
}
```

Simply deleting the field's tracking areas when creating it wasn't quite enough, because the field was in a scroll view and sometimes the tracking areas would be re-created.

Comment: Glad my suggestion was helpful! I wasn't completely sure it was the right route.