# Tacking control of NSTrackingArea Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, crash, nstokenfield, nstokenfieldcell

I'd like to make an NSTokenField ignore mouse events when my screen is loading.So if I move the cursor over that text field the application is getting crashed with the crash logs

> *** -[RSTokenFieldCell respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x611000985c00

I have tried overriding the updateTrackingAreas,trackingAreas, but no luck. Could someone let me know how to use this. I have [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876713/how-to-make-an-nscontrol-e-g-nstokenfield-ignore-mouse-events). Doing this completely disables the tracking options. Please suggest if any solution.